# Finding a way to create a simple timer for a game server

Tags: c++, timer

I'm creating a [game server](https://github.com/ipr0gr4mipas2/GrowtopiaServer) for [Growtopia](https://growtopiagame.com) in C++, server works great. If you'd like to find more about the game, have a look at the link above. Anyways, My goal is to create a function or some code for "PlayMods", Essentially PlayMods are just item effects just like how potions work in minecraft, the "PlayMods" run off on a certain time and stop giving you the effect at a certain time. I would like to give a player a "PlayMod" for example, freeze effect for 10 seconds, then in 10 seconds the "PlayMod" is removed from the player.

I've tried the sleep function, obviously that wouldn't work because it would sleep the server for 'x' amount of seconds. I've tried while functions, dumb way of doing it but didn't work anyways, crashed the server. Not sure how else I could do it.

Here is some examples of players giving/recieving "PlayMods" in the "Main" server of Growtopia. (couldn't find many videos sorry)

List of consumables in the game: https://growtopia.fandom.com/wiki/Items/Consumables

Here is a video where a user uses "DuctTape" on themselves and it gives them the ducttape effect for 10 MINUTES. https://youtu.be/FWc_-cxIu3E?t=3

Any recommendations or help would be fantastic. Thank you!!

I'm not the best at C++, However that doesn't stop me from trying and I'm still trying to learn. Here is also a link to a copy of the server's code made by someone else on github. https://github.com/ipr0gr4mipas2/GrowtopiaServer

Photos of playmods
[Showing a list of playmods active in a users info dialog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F25jU.png)

Comment: *I'm not the best at C++* not surprising with [Highlander's Law and all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs).

Comment: But seriously, don't create your own timer. There will almost certainly be one built into the game API that you can use or adapt to your use.

Comment: how about SetTimer function from winapi?

Comment: Your question would leave a better impression if it started with a question, rather than starting with an advertisement for / endorsement of your favorite game. Please review [ask].

Comment: @JaMiT , It's not an advertisement / endorsement for the game, I'm simply giving links to give a further understanding of the game and what I have to work with and what I'm working on. It's more or so giving a better understanding.

Comment: @SillyMonkey You provided a link to the game *before* asking your question. That gives the impression that you are more interested in promoting the game than asking your question. From [ask]: *"In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title."* The faster you get to your question, the more serious your question appears. Start with the context *necessary* to frame your question, proceed to the question, **then** go into other context that might influence the nature of answers (such as server documentation, not the main game site).

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post but what heres what I would do.
Set a variable of the effect EG:

`"int blindness = 0;"`

And then have an if statement - if the effect reaches a number, apply an effect.  You can simply have a for loop in an if statement.

If you need the length of time to vary, you can have the delay vary as a multiplication of the variable for blindness EG:

```
float blindness = 0;

//*Player does something to get the effect*

if(blindness > 2.0){
    for(i = 0, i < 50, i++){
        This would be the code for the actual effect.   
    }
}
```

Comment: Good way of potentially approaching this, I'll make sure to discuss this with my teacher and see what he thinks of this idea. But it's something I could do, my teacher also suggests using the time header and that.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If you want to use the time/date im sure that could definitely work using a variable to store the time ( time(); ) and simply an if statement to get the variable again and if it is x amount of secods mroe than when you last checked stop the effect although from my past experiences (Albeit not much)  running servers with getting the date for those has not worked well for me.  But if your teacher says that I would follow what they say.

Comment: This looks like what we call a [busy spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) loop. Somewhere in the loop you will want to relinquish the CPU to allow it to do other work (or even just stop sucking as much electricity from the battery)

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! I had not heard of one of those before! I will do some research on how to relenquish the cpu!